# email actions without registering with google?

Tags: google-schemas

I am trying to send **internal emails** with some [`go-to action`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/go-to-action) (as in: we're using google apps for business, sending emails from ad-hoc services to internal / same-domain users) . The [restrictions for registering with google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/registering-with-google) are pretty strict.

Is there any way to have the actions show up properly when the emails are sent from the same domain to the same domain? One example is some internal defect tracking system, and I'd like to have a [`ViewAction`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/go-to-action#view_action):

```
...
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "url": "http://bugzilla.mydomain.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4318"
  },
  "description": "See this bug directly on Bugzilla."
}
</script>
...
more details about the bug.
...
```

This is one of many examples where we have some tools internally and we'd like to use actions but we **don't want to register them** all; in particular when emails come from users rather than particular machines.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there's no way to enable internal emails like yours without whitelisting the sender for the general public. However, your use case is a legitimate one and I'll bring it up with the team.

Comment: thank you. please let me know if you need more specific details.

Comment: I'll wait until you have a some feedback from your team; my hope is that the use case gets accepted and your answer changes to show how to use the actions specifically for tools that are internal to a domain (using google apps for business). thank you.

Comment: I'll update the answer with any news, but please monitor our Release Notes page (https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/release-notes) in case I forget :)